# Alignment of equations with implies and equals to

Tags: equations, amsmath, alignment

In `amsmath` package, the following doesn't get aligned properly. Here is the code.

```
\begin{alignat*}{2}
& 0 &= \dfrac{1}{4}(2(-1)+1)+C\mathrm{e}^{2(-1)}\\
& \implies 0 &= \dfrac{-1}{4}+C\mathrm{e}^{-2}\\
& \implies \dfrac{1}{4}\mathrm{e}^2 &= C\\
& \implies C &= \dfrac{1}{4}\mathrm{e}^2
\end{alignat*}
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: You can also [use `align`](https://pastebin.com/1CS9cXUc).

Comment: You should understand that 2 alignment points  per row require `3 &`, not 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
&& 0 &= \dfrac{1}{4}(2(-1)+1)+C\mathrm{e}^{2(-1)}\\
& \implies& 0 &= \dfrac{-1}{4}+C\mathrm{e}^{-2}\\
& \implies& \dfrac{1}{4}\mathrm{e}^2 &= C\\
& \implies& C &= \dfrac{1}{4}\mathrm{e}^2
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]